Vue Router Not Reflecting Routes, Stays on Home Page
I'm working on a Vue 3 project and encountering an issue where the Vue Router is not reflecting the correct routes. When I navigate to any route, such as /cars or /admin, the URL does not update and the application stays on the home page.
import { createMemoryHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";

import HomePage from "../views/website/index.vue";
import CarsPage from "../views/website/CarsPage.vue";
import AdminLayout from "../components/admin/AdminLayout.vue";
import AdminDashboard from "../views/admin/index.vue"; // Assuming AdminDashboard is exported as default

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomePage,
  },
  {
    path: "/cars",
    name: "cars",
    component: CarsPage,
  },
  {
    path: "/admin", // Make sure to add '/admin' as a separate route
    component: AdminLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: "", // Making '/admin' itself redirect to '/admin/dashboard'
        redirect: "dashboard",
      },
      {
        path: "dashboard",
        name: "admin-dashboard",
        component: AdminDashboard,
        meta: { requiresAuth: true },
      },
      // Add more admin routes here if needed
    ],
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createMemoryHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;

And this is how I'm loading it in main.js:
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Antd from "ant-design-vue";

import router from "./router/router";
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(Antd);

app.use(router);
router.isReady().then(() => {
  console.log("helllo");
  app.mount("#app");
});

Somehow when I go /admin it does not reflect and stays at HomePage
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Header for website pages -->
    <header>
      <!-- Include website-specific header content here -->
    </header>

    <!-- Router view for website pages -->
    <router-view />
    <!-- {{ $route }} -->

    <!-- Footer for website pages -->
    <footer>
      <!-- Include website-specific footer content here -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Router view for admin pages -->
    <router-view name="admin" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Footer from "./components/Footer.vue";
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Header, Footer },
  created() {
    this.$router.push("/admin/dashboard");
  },
};
</script>

When I try to navigate to any route like /admin or /cars, the URL does not change and the application remains on the home page. The console output shows the following route information when I attempt to navigate:

What does the console output? Also, I am not familiar with router.isReady().then((), mind trying to remove it and restart your server? What about your Vue devtools? Is anything weird in it? Also, do you mind clicking on a button to try out a navigation or maybe a router-link? How did you create your Vue app btw? This CLI does it pretty well and with something fully functional: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html

this the result, I added the isReady based on some answer on the web but it didnt help and does not change anything. I do get the hello result form console.log(). also the page is available because when I redirect to it using $router.push() it opens that page.

I am not sure about the answer we're talking about, it is documented here but let's start by removing it first to have something functional to begin with. Not sure about the second part of your answers, but I meant the Vue devtools as in choosing all the paths + where you currently are from the devtools' point of view.

Do you mind maybe sharing a [repro] or trying to create a project with the CLI as listed above?

I have already removed the first part and the result is the same, as for minimal reproducible example, I am not sure how I can do that for my vue-app, just did setup for a new project I didnt even add complexity its just simple components with no dynamics.

I have resolved the issues the problem is with createMemoryHistory() I replaced it wiht createWebHistory() and it worked

"output shows the following route information" - there's no info. "the URL does not change" - you use memory router, so this isn't expected

The issue is related to the use of createMemoryHistory instead of createWebHistory. createMemoryHistory is typically used for server-side rendering or testing, while createWebHistory is used for client-side navigation in a typical web application.

I think "Router view for admin pages" have to be inside "Router view for website pages".
So the code will be
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <!-- Header for website pages -->
        <header>
        <!-- Include website-specific header content here -->
        </header>

        <!-- Router view for website pages -->
        <router-view>
            <!-- Router view for admin pages -->
            <router-view name="admin" />
        <router-view />
        <!-- {{ $route }} -->

        <!-- Footer for website pages -->
        <footer>
            <!-- Include website-specific footer content here -->
        </footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Footer from "./components/Footer.vue";
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
export default {
    name: "App",
    components: { Header, Footer },
    created() {
        this.$router.push("/admin/dashboard");
    },
};
</script>

